# "driver.switchTo.window() " doesn't help in switching windows/tabs

Tags: webdriver

In my test I have four tabs opened in same browser window. I want that I iterate through all 
tabs, perform some task in each tab and quit entire session using `driver.quit();`.

This is what I tried:
Pre-Condition: All four tabs are open.

```
ArrayList<String> windowhandles = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        System.out.println("got handles");
        for (int i = 0; i<windowhandles.size();i++ ){
            System.out.println("inside windowhandles for loop");
            driver.switchTo().window(windowhandles.get(i));
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
            /*** perform some tasks ***/     

        }driver.quit();
```

Above code will remain at the first tab and print `page title` of all tabs, without switching to them. Why its not switching, what wrong am I doing?

Comment: I don't quite follow, is it printing out a `title` for each page or just repeating the `title` for the first page?

Comment: why `driver.switchTo().window(windowhandles.get(i));` doesn't switch to desired window, that's the problem. Once you successfully switched to window its upto you, you want to click or get the page title.

Comment: When you say "It doesn't switch" do you mean that it doesn't get the corresponding `title` and/or you don't see the tab change in the browser? Because you won't see the tab change in case you're expecting that to happen.

Comment: Yes I don't see tab change, but why I would not see that happening?If that wouldn't happen how `webdriver` would click on element present on that page(tab)?

Comment: Because `webdriver` doesn't need to 'see' like we do. It can interact with the elements on the page/tab it has been told to switch to regardless of which 'is on top' to a viewer. `Webdriver` can be run headless, so it doesn't need the browser to have rendered on the screen for it to work.

Comment: But why this is working `for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);}` is working. It can switch to new window and back to parent window if I want `driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56198/discussion-between-paul-and-mark-rowlands).